# What is the point of creating external configuration file in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file, configuration

I am new to spring. But here a concept is confusing me and am also not getting a clear answer. I am not sure what is the point of creating an external configuration file? Like, what is the point of application.properties ? We can also use the features via code right? Also, if we make a change to the configuration file then we also have to rerun the application right? Then what is the point of doing such a thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As with any configuration, it's better to be able to just switch some values in a properties file rather than hard coding the values and having to recompile the code every time we change a value.

Comment: Your development environment won't be the same as your production environment. Do you intend to build an application per environment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of application.properties is to be able to change some properties without re-compiling your code. So in big companies no QA phase, delivery needed

You just change some properties, restart the application and ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

The `application.properties` or `application.yml` file contains the **environment variables**. This is quite similar with constants in your application. The importance of externalizing it is to minimize updating the source code when some configuration changes.

Example: Your app's database migrated to another server.
You can just update your `application.properties` file instead of opening your `DBConfig.java`.

Another benefit is if your team is using Spring Cloud Config Server where your app connects and fetches the testing/staging/production configurations. This means that your configurations are not tightly coupled into your app's source code.

Whereas if you do it directly into your source code, then every time there's a change in the configuration (be it database connection, connection to other services, etc) you'll have to update your code then rebuild and deploy.